# Cannot import geopandas using reticulate in RStudio when knitting with knitr

Tags: python, r, knitr, geopandas, reticulate

I am trying to knit an Rmd file using reticulate and Python inside of a virtualenv. 
The following is my R set up chunk:

````
```{r r-setup}
library(reticulate)

venv_path <- "/path/to/venv/"
use_virtualenv(venv_path, required = TRUE)
```
````

This works as expected. However, the next step breaks when I try to import geopandas:

````
```{python}
import geopandas as gpd
```
````

The traceback is as follows:

```
Error in py_module_import... OSError: Could not find lib c or load any variants...
```

The traceback error points to the shapely package `from shapely.geometry import shape, Point File`. Other Python libraries load with no issue within the chunk e.g. `import os`.

From these messages, I'm guessing that it is not loading the OGR/GDAL bindings. However, I'm not sure how to solve this.

`import geopandas` runs without error when I run the chunk inside of the notebook e.g. not knitting.  It also works within the `repl_python()` shell of my project. So the issue seems to be principally with knitr and knitting.

My RStudio version is: 1.1.456.

The output of session_info() is:

> sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib

locale:
[1] en_NZ.UTF-8/en_NZ.UTF-8/en_NZ.UTF-8/C/en_NZ.UTF-8/en_NZ.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] reticulate_1.10 stringr_1.3.1   dplyr_0.7.6     ggplot2_3.0.0  

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] Rcpp_0.12.18     pillar_1.3.0     compiler_3.5.1   plyr_1.8.4      
[5] bindr_0.1.1      tools_3.5.1      digest_0.6.17    packrat_0.4.9-3 
[9] jsonlite_1.5     evaluate_0.11    tibble_1.4.2     gtable_0.2.0    
[13] lattice_0.20-35  pkgconfig_2.0.2  rlang_0.2.2      Matrix_1.2-14   
[17] yaml_2.2.0       bindrcpp_0.2.2   withr_2.1.2      knitr_1.20      
[21] rprojroot_1.3-2  grid_3.5.1       tidyselect_0.2.4 glue_1.3.0      
[25] R6_2.2.2         rmarkdown_1.10   purrr_0.2.5      magrittr_1.5    
[29] scales_1.0.0     backports_1.1.2  htmltools_0.3.6  assertthat_0.2.0
[33] colorspace_1.3-2 stringi_1.2.4    lazyeval_0.2.1   munsell_0.5.0   
[37] crayon_1.3.4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this by removing the "DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH" which points to my brew installed R libraries. 
The solution was within a python chunk as follows:

````
```{python}
import os
FALLBACK_PATH = {"DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH" : "/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.5.1/lib/R/lib"}
del os.environ["DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH"]

import geopandas

# Reset the environmental variable.
os.environ.update(FALLBACK_PATH)
```
````

I'm not sure if this is the cleanest solution but it works. Also not sure if this is a Mac OSX problem only as well.